# Prevent CSS stardust effect from losing shape on narrow screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I'm planning to implement the following stardust effect as a background to my page: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/aBbmgW

The problem that I'm experiencing is that when the width of the browser window drops below 700px the rays in the stardust effect become distorted as in the following image:

[image]

Would you know what causes the distortion in shape and how to fix it?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="starbust-wheel">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #03a9f4;
}

.starbust-wheel {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.starbust-wheel > li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 5%, transparent 25%);
}

.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(18deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(36deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(54deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(72deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotate(108deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(7) {
    transform: rotate(126deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(8) {
    transform: rotate(144deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(9) {
    transform: rotate(162deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(10) {
    transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(11) {
    transform: rotate(198deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(12) {
    transform: rotate(216deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(13) {
    transform: rotate(234deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(14) {
    transform: rotate(252deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(15) {
    transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(16) {
    transform: rotate(288deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(17) {
    transform: rotate(306deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(18) {
    transform: rotate(324deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(19) {
    transform: rotate(342deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(20) {
    transform: rotate(360deg)  skewX(72deg);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use an SVG. That's an awful lot of HTML & CSS for a background?

Comment: To explain why you're seeing what you're seeing though - this is due to how you're making that triangle shape. Since it's just a corner of a skewed rectangle with dimensions dependent on the viewport dimensions, once the ratio of viewport height to width is high enough, the corner of the skewed rectangle comes into view and dispels the effect that this is a triangle. (You can confirm this by using a web inspector to highlight the element as you manipulate the viewport.) In terms of solving this though...haha, that makes my head hurt. Go with an SVG. =P

Comment: @Serlite You are right ... but I think that increasing the width and height of the li to 100% would solve the problem

Comment: @vals It makes the problem less apparent, but at extreme dimension ratios the second corner still shows up. Perhaps that'd be adequate for the OP's needs though, only he can determine that!

Comment: I will go with @Archer's answer, but I will look into creating this effect with SVG as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're just shrinking due to the relative size you've set at 50%.  If you change that to 100% then it looks exactly the same but doesn't exhibit the problem you've had.  I'd also recommend changing the height to 100% so you don't have the problem if the page height goes too low...

```
.starbust-wheel > li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Updated example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbWXga

You'll probably want to change the gradient slightly, as this has brightened it up a bit from the original.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create a couple of different backgrounds based on device widths...maybe something for 1920x1080, then a few more for smaller devices...

Implement then using media queries based on min-width ( mobile first and all :-) ) or use javascript...

SVG is also a option, maybe if you want something animated?